# Get Item from DataGridCellInfo in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in WPF. The DataGridCellInfo contains `Column`, `IsValid` and `Item`.

```
private void ProjectsDatagrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
            var selected = ProjectsDatagrid.SelectedCells[0];
        }
```

I tried:

```
var foo = selected.Item.Name

var foo2 = selected.Item[Name]
```

How am I supposed to get the value from the field `Name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast `Item` to your type, e.g.:

```
var dataObject = selected.Item as YourClass;
if (dataObject != null)
{
    string name = dataObject.Name;
    //...
}
```

...where `YourClass` is a custom class with a `Name` property.